# Two barcode quantities in one barcode

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard-events, barcode-scanner

I am working on reading a barcode containing two barcodes from a scanner that provides the UPC barcode and a quantity purchased in a single barcode.  The barcode scanner is a USB emulating a keyboard (typical out of the box configuration).  I cannot use pre and/or post characters to differentiate the barcodes.  The scanner provides a return key after each of the two codes.  When I scan to Notepad, I get the UPC code, a return character, the quantity and another return character.

I am coding in C# using Visual Studio 2010 Pro.  I have tried using a textbox that accepts returns and setting it to multiline but I only get the UPC code.  I have found no way thus far to capture the quantity amount as well.  HELP!!!

Comment: Have you tried expanding the .Height of the TextBox? It will not expand to fit it's contents. Try making it taller and scanning again to rule out that error.

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to get the codes into a text box, or is your goal to capture the codes and use them in a program somehow?  If it's the latter, you probably want to make your own widget that accepts key events, and then getting the return characters should come naturally.

Comment: My goal is to capture the codes and place them in the appropriate cells of a DataGridView.  I am building a customized application to serve quilt shops in maintaining inventory, POS and track customers and their tendencies.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DataGridView, but can you insert custom widgets into it and write your own input handlers for them?  If so, you should consider it, because you'll have full access to the "keystrokes."